# Quarkus - configure logging with kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus

According to the [official resource](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging), logging configuration relies on *application.properties* file.

Now I need to have several configuration according to the cluster in use (let's say we have the typical dev, staging and production environments, thus dev should have a DEBUG level and production at least INFO).

At first I thought using Kubernetes [ConfigMaps](https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes-config), but I can't see any connection with quarkus logging.

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

This is my ConfigMap

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: kube-cm-config-map
namespace: default
uid: d992d86f-c247-471d-8e31-53e9a1858b76
resourceVersion: '8484'
creationTimestamp: '2021-04-22T13:12:43Z'
managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    apiVersion: v1
    time: '2021-04-22T13:12:43Z'
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
        'f:data':
        .: {}
        'f:myenv': {}
        'f:myname': {}
    - manager: kubectl-edit
    operation: Update
    apiVersion: v1
    time: '2021-04-22T16:52:18Z'
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
        'f:data':
        'f:log.file.level': {}
    - manager: dashboard
    operation: Update
    apiVersion: v1
    time: '2021-04-23T08:03:06Z'
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
        'f:data':
        'f:quarkus.log.file.level': {}
data:
log.file.level: DEBUG
myenv: cl1
myname: cluster1
quarkus.log.file.level: DEBUG
```

EDIT2

This is my config map (through command kubectl edit cm ):

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_ENABLE: "true"
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_FORMAT: '%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n'
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_LEVEL: ERROR
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_PATH: /tmp/kube-cm.log
myenv: cl1
myname: cluster 1b
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
creationTimestamp: "2021-04-22T13:12:43Z"
name: kube-cm-config-map
namespace: default
resourceVersion: "39810"
uid: d992d86f-c247-471d-8e31-53e9a1858b76
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved by editing the cm in the following way:

```
data:
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_ENABLE: "true"
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_FORMAT: '%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n'
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_LEVEL: ERROR
QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_PATH: /tmp/kube-cm.log
```

Then I set **application.properties** on quarkus with:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.env.configmaps=kube-cm-config-map
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use a `ConfigMap` in Quarkus to read runtime configuration.

The first is to let Quarkus query the API server using the `quarkus-kubernetes-config` extension which is described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes-config).

The second way to configure the Kubernetes `Deployment` to turn `ConfigMap` values into environment variables for the Pod. This can be done with the `quarkus-kubernetes` extension which is described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes#environment-variables-from-keyvalue-pairs).

So you would add the proper quarkus logging configuration (i.e a key value pair) in the ConfigMap and then use one of the above methods to use that at runtime

Comment: Sorry but I still unable to make it work. Tried with configuring on cm:
"quarkus.log.file.level": "DEBUG" or "log.file.level": "DEBUG", but still cannot see any log trace. See also my edit on first post. Thank you

Comment: Why are you enabling the debug level for files only?

Comment: This is just a code snippet. What I want to do is to keep different log level for each environment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kubernetes resource yaml to deploy your app, use the snippet below to push your custom ConfigMap as environment variables to your applicaton (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables):

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: 
          image:
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: kube-cm-config-map
```

Use a different ConfigMap for each environment but with the same name. If your environments (dev/qa/etc) are Kubernetes namespaces, then it is very easy to setup. Just duplicate the ConfigMap in each namespace, and change the log level value in each namespace.

Also, change the naming convention for your ConfigMap properties  from `log.file.level` to `LOG_FILE_LEVEL`
See https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#environment_variables

Comment: Tried to set all possibles values in config maps, but nothing changes.

Comment: @FabrizioStellato, did you enable logging for file: QUARKUS_LOG_FILE_ENABLE=true